# Angular HostListener not working as expected with ALT key

Tags: angular, typescript, keylistener

I have recently started using angular and am facing a very basic issue.

I have added a keydown listener to my component as follows:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDownListener(event: KeyboardEvent) {
......
}
```

Issue is while using ALT key. When I press ALT key for first time, this method gets called. But afterwards method is not called when I press ALT key.

Other keys are working fine, and pressing them always invoke this method.

What is that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It appears that it should work [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dy4cdv?file=src%2Florem.directive.ts). Are you getting any errors? could you post the code that executes when alt is pressed?

Comment: No error. I just have a consolo.log('Hi') statement in the method.

Comment: I tested with your link, and I observe same issue. On pressing ALT multiple times, 'triggered' is printed just once on console.